# Variance of stochastic process $MA(2)$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $\left\{ X_t \right\} $ be a stochastic process $MA(2)$ such that $X_t = Z_t + 0.8Z_{t-2}$. Where $\left\{ Z_t \right\} $ is White Noise $WN(0,1)$.

Compute variance of $$\frac{X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4}{4}$$

I don't have any idea how can I compute it. Could you give me a tip?

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Tip: Write $\frac14(X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4)$
 as a linear combination of $(Z_{-1},Z_0,Z_1,Z_2,Z_3,Z_4)$.